# How to add a SwiftUI object in UIkit

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, uikit, storyboard

I have already used Hosting View Controller with connecting my swiftui class to use SwiftUI in storyboard (UIkit) but the issue is I don't want to use it in another page I want to add SwiftUI variable (graphic) to the same page as I created with UIkit. How can I put some stuff in UIkit via SwiftUI, is there something like Container hosting View? there is Container View which helps you to add views in View but you can't edit that like editing Hosting View Controller. Please give me a hand.
I showed where I want the SwiftUI in image below 
[image]

Comment: Look up `UIHostingController` and `UIViewController` `addChild`

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use UIKit in SwiftUI, you make use of **UIViewControllerRepresentable** (A view that represents a UIKit view controller).

if you add UiViewControllerRepresentable Protocol.
you can UIViewController in SwiftUI.

```
struct ViewControllerRepresentation: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    
}
```

this is Example

```
final class RedLabel: UILabel {
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
 
        textColor = .red
    }
}
 
struct RepresentableRedLabel: UIViewRepresentable {
    var text: String
 
    let redLabel = RedLabel()
 
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UILabel {
        redLabel
    }
 
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UILabel, context: Context) {
        redLabel.text = text
    }
}
```